# Export AWS codeartifact auth token and use them to restore nuget packages in docker file

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile, aws-codeartifact

In one of my csproj is consuming nuget packages from AWS codeartifact. I'm suppose to run this in docker. I'm trying to restore nuget from AWS codeartifact in dockerfile.( As shown below)

RUN dotnet restore test.csproj -nowarn:msb3202,nul50 -s  -s

And in nuget config file I have been using AWS auth token generated manually from outside and saving the daily as it is getting expired.

Is there any way I get this auth token at runtime in docker file or do something so that I don't have to change this when expired.

Please let me if there is any solution

Thanks in advance!